# VC2013 incorrect MSPDB120.DLL

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker-errors

During linking I get this message:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1101: incorrect MSPDB120.DLL version; recheck installation of this product`

I have seen solutions for similar errors on previous versions of VC2013 but those did not work for me. Those include:

1. running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat`
2. adding %VS120COMNTOOLS% environment variable to the PATH environment variable
3. Reinstall or Repair the installation of MSVC2013 (NOT RECOMMENDED)

The first time I got this error I went ahead with a full reinstall of VC2013. I chose to take this rout because I thought maybe I had screwed up the install by installing older versions of VC after installing VC2013. Although reinstalling worked the first time, I can't recommend doing this. The MS installer seems rather broken and hung up on me on repeated attempts, resulting in the loss of 5+ hours of my life.

What are some other solutions to this problem if the first 2 options do not work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open Task Manager.

Check for the currently running processes `mspdbsrv.exe` and kill it if it is running and try again. I don't know why this works, but I have to do it every once in a while. The process comes back each time you compile and it seems random whether or not it gets stuck on this step.

Alternatively, if you do not need debug information generated, you can skip this process altogether by setting:

- Project Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info ->
  `No`

Comment: Your machine sounds rather messed up.  This answer doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Killing extraneous MSVC processes solves the problem, what is not explained? Of course I cannot explain why it happens in the first place - I didn't develop MSVC.

Comment: +1 resolved it for me. However I did cancel a build previously that got stuck, I think that is the root cause

Comment: This worked for me.  If running headless, you can use 'Taskkill /im mspdbsrv.exe' instead of Task Manager.

Comment: One of the reasons this happens is because when "entering" a system via SSH or certain other means, sometimes these means don't properly handle the user profile, causing the environment to be incomplete. Due to that, several tools will act up ... so it's not necessarily "the machine" that is messed up but often simply the environment in which a certain job is running.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen.  In my case, I had a statically-linked shared 'helper' lib that was compiled with the cl.exe CRT flags "-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE", whereas my target app that linked in this helper lib did not have these set.  Once I added these flags to the app's cl.exe flags, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error message when another compile (jenkins) is still running in the background.
Waiting for it to finish, and retry fixes the error.